# Resolver undifined index

Tags: php, mysql, índices, undefined

Estou tentando **criar** uma **tabela** com dados de uma base de dados [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), porém quando abro a página, mostra alguns resultados e depois acima aparece esse erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: DESCRIÇÃO TAREFA in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\reghoras\index.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Undefined index: DURAÇÃO TAREFA in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\reghoras\index.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: PENDENTES in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\reghoras\index.php on line 29

Imagem da estrutura da base de dados:

[image: Imagem da estrutura da base de dados]

Registo de Horas

```
<body>
    <center><h2>Registo de Horas 2016</h2></center>
    <br>
    <?php
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        include('connect_mysql.php');

        $sqlget = "SELECT * FROM `bdreghoras` where id !=0";
        $sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('erro a obter os dados');

        echo "<table border= '1' cellpadding= '10'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Processo</th><th>Data (dd/mm/aaaa)</th><th>Utilizador</th><th>Descrição da Tarefa</th><th>Hora de inicio</th><th>Hora de Fim</th><th>Duração de Tarefa</th><th>Pendentes</th><th>Local</th></tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PROCESSO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DATA'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['UTILIZADOR'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIÇÃO TAREFA'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['HORA INICIO'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['HORA FIM'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DURAÇÃO TAREFA'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PENDENTES'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['LOCAL'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
</body>
```

Não sei como resolve-lo preciso de ajuda

Comment: pode postar seu código PHP, e a estrutura da tabela? Isso ajuda muito a gente identificar o problema. Bem vindo ao SOPT :)

Comment: Você tem certeza que em todas as linhas essas três colunas citadas possuem valor?

Comment: o problema esta na nomeclatura das colunas pois possuem espaço, tente usar um `var_dump` para ver como os nomes estão sendo exibidos.

Comment: é altamente recomendado que não se utilize caracteres acentuados e espaços na estrutura do banco, pois estes podem sofrer diferença de conversão.

Answer (score 3):

Antes de mais, a estrutura da sua tabela deverá ser a seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE `bdreghoras` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PROCESSO` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `DATA` DATE NOT NULL,
  `UTILIZADOR` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRICAO_TAREFA` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `HORA_INICIO` TIME NOT NULL,
  `HORA_FIM` TIME NOT NULL,
  `DURACAO_TAREFA` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `PEDENTES` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `LOCAL` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

Em seguida, deves alterar o seu script PHP da seguinte forma:

```
// ...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PROCESSO'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DATA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['UTILIZADOR'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRICAO_TAREFA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['HORA_INICIO'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['HORA_FIM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DURACAO_TAREFA'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PENDENTES'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LOCAL'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

### Undefined Index

Esse erro ocorre quando tenta-se acessar um índice inexistente de um array. Esse erro é muito comum com iniciantes usando Query String. O famoso exemplo:

```
<?php
$pag = $_GET['pag'];
?>
```

Se não existe a variável “pag” na URL, dará este erro:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pag in teste.php on line 2

Para evitar esse erro, sempre verifique se o índice existe. A função isset resolve facilmente esse problema:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['pag'] ) )
{
    $pag = $_GET['pag'];
}
else
{
    $pag = 'valor padrão';
}
```

O código pode ser reescrito sda seguinte forma, usando o Operador Condicional Ternário:

```
$pag = isset( $_GET['pag'] ) ? $_GET['pag'] : 'valor_padrao';
```

### O SEU PROBLEMA:

> NUNCA SE DEVE UTILIZAR **ESPAÇOS**, NEM **ACENTOS** E DE PREFERÊNCIA sem caixa alta PARA TÍTULOS DE COLUNAS DE SUA TABELA.

Você tem `DESCRIÇÃO TAREFA, PENDENTES, DURAÇÃO TAREFA` que não estão sendo encontrados nas variáveis:

```
...                   POR QUE???????

            //Erro de Acento na hora da conversão
            echo"<td>" . $row['DESCRIÇÃO TAREFA'] . "</td>";

            //No banco ta PEdente
            echo "<td>" . $row['PENDENTES'] . "</td>";

            //Erro de Acento na hora da conversão
            echo "<td>" . $row['DURAÇÃO TAREFA'] . "</td>";
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

primeiramente indico que não utiliza acentuações, cedilha e espaços em seu banco de dados por boas práticas.

Para resolver esse problema, dê um `var_dump($row)` dentro do laço `while` para ver como que está sendo retornado os campos, após isso, atualize os índices.

Este erro:
`Notice: Undefined index: PENDENTES in C:\xampp\htdocs\reghoras\index.php on line 29` está relacionado ao erro de digitação, seu campo no banco de dados está nomeado como `pedentes` e não `peNdentes`.

Em relação aos outros erros, teste executar essa linha de código antes da consulta para que o banco de dados esteja no formato utf-8.

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "SET CHARSET UTF8");
```

Abs.